# Google Map API inside a xhtml jsf page

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, jsf, xhtml

I would like to insert the Google Map API inside an xhtml jsf page.
The probleme is that when i insert the tag :

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyAPIKey&libraries=visualization&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

The server give me the error :

> Error Parsing /listUsers.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 21] Reference to the entity "libraries" must end with ';'.

The error happens specificaly when I add the src attribute in the script tag.

I'm sure that the script is the issue because the xhtml page is very simple :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Google Map API on xhtml</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

    </h:head>

    <h:body>


    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyAPIKey&libraries=visualization&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

I'm sure the script is working since i manage to display the Google Map on a regular html page.

What should I do to include the map wiithout having trouble ?

Comment: in the browser developer tools console, what does `document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]` return? One problem could be that there is no `head` element ... which is where that google api script loads other scripts! Try adding an empty `<head></head>` element before your `<h:body>`

Comment: There is <h:head> </h:head> élément, doesn't it count ?

Comment: Did you try what I suggested as the first sentence in the comment? No, it doesn't count

Comment: Adding the head didn't work. And i can't print the content of document.getElementByTagName(head) because of the Jee error. But I inspect the page i can see a script tag with Google js function inside.

Comment: `and i can't print the content of document.getElementByTagName(head)` - two errors in that ... it's getElementsByTagName (the s is important) and it's the string "head" not a variable name head ... and your error wouldn't stop the browser developer tools console from giving you that information